# How to show data into list in Android

Tags: android, list, arraylist, android-recyclerview

In my application I want show some data in `recyclerView` and i get this data from server. 
I use `Retrofit` for **send** or **get** requests from android to server.
When run the application, it's showing `response.body().getData().size()` is **0**, but in **[PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/apps)** I see the following data:

**I write below code for get data :**

```
private void getComments() {
    CommentSendData sendData = new CommentSendData();
    sendData.setEntityID(7);
    sendData.setReviewType(5);
    sendData.setReviewUserType(0);
    sendData.setEntityID(newsID);
    sendData.setCelebrityID(0);
    sendData.setPageIndex(0);
    sendData.setPageSize(10);

    InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
    Call<CommentResponse> call = api.getComments(sendData);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<CommentResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CommentResponse> call, Response<CommentResponse> response) {
            Toast.makeText(NewsDetailActivity.this, "" + response.body().getData().size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(NewsDetailActivity.this, "" + call.isExecuted(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CommentResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

When show this `Toast` :`Toast.makeText(NewsDetailActivity.this, "" + call.isExecuted(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` show me **true** in `toast`.

and when show this `Toast` : `Toast.makeText(NewsDetailActivity.this, "" + response.body().getData().size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` , show me **0** in `toast` .

**My Adapter codes:**

```
public class CommentsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentsListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<CommentData> model;

    public CommentsListAdapter(Context context, List<CommentData> model) {
        this.context = context;
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public CommentsListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_comment, parent, false);

        return new CommentsListAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CommentsListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.row_commentNameTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(model.get(position).getOwner().getName()));
        holder.row_commentCommentTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(model.get(position).getText()));
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(model.get(position).getOwner().getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model,
                                                   Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(holder.row_commentProfileImage);
        holder.row_commentLikeTxt.setText(model.get(position).getLikeCount() + "");
        holder.row_commentReplayTxt.setText(model.get(position).getRepliesCount() + "");
        holder.row_commentDateTxt.setText(model.get(position).getSubmitDate() + " " + model.get(position).getSubmitTime());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return model.size();
    }

    public void addNewItem(List<CommentData> newContent) {
        int start = this.model.size();
        int end = newContent.size();
        model.addAll(newContent);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {
        model.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private CircleImageView row_commentProfileImage;
        private TextView row_commentNameTxt, row_commentCommentTxt, row_commentLikeTxt, row_commentReplayTxt, row_commentDateTxt;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            row_commentProfileImage = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_commentProfileImage);
            row_commentNameTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_commentNameTxt);
            row_commentCommentTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_commentCommentTxt);
            row_commentLikeTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_commentLikeTxt);
            row_commentReplayTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_commentReplayTxt);
            row_commentDateTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_commentDateTxt);

        }
    }
}
```

**CommentResponse code:**

```
public class CommentResponse {
    @SerializedName("statusCode")
    @Expose
    private Integer statusCode;
    @SerializedName("statusMessage")
    @Expose
    private String statusMessage;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<CommentData> data = null;

    public Integer getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public String getStatusMessage() {
        return statusMessage;
    }

    public void setStatusMessage(String statusMessage) {
        this.statusMessage = statusMessage;
    }

    public List<CommentData> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<CommentData> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

**CommentData model :**

```
public class CommentData {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("text")
    @Expose
    private String text;
    @SerializedName("likeCount")
    @Expose
    private Integer likeCount;
    @SerializedName("repliesCount")
    @Expose
    private Integer repliesCount;
    @SerializedName("submitDate")
    @Expose
    private String submitDate;
    @SerializedName("submitTime")
    @Expose
    private String submitTime;
    @SerializedName("owner")
    @Expose
    private CommentOwner owner;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Integer getLikeCount() {
        return likeCount;
    }

    public void setLikeCount(Integer likeCount) {
        this.likeCount = likeCount;
    }

    public Integer getRepliesCount() {
        return repliesCount;
    }

    public void setRepliesCount(Integer repliesCount) {
        this.repliesCount = repliesCount;
    }

    public String getSubmitDate() {
        return submitDate;
    }

    public void setSubmitDate(String submitDate) {
        this.submitDate = submitDate;
    }

    public String getSubmitTime() {
        return submitTime;
    }

    public void setSubmitTime(String submitTime) {
        this.submitTime = submitTime;
    }

    public CommentOwner getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(CommentOwner owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

Why when run application show me **0** data but in **PostMan** show data ?!

Comment: "When run the application, it's showing response.body().getData().size() is 0" -- check `code()`, `message()`, and `errorBody()`, as perhaps you are getting an HTTP error.

Comment: @CommonsWare, are you here my friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a few reasons for that

1.) There might be some error while typing the base or secondary URL. Please cross check them. And Check another thing that "/" came after base URL so no need to use it before secondary URL.

2.) Please cross check the the payloads as they must be accurate. If you don't know how to create accurate payloads then follow this spinet.

```
private JsonObject makeJsonObjectPayload() {

        JsonObject requestBean = new JsonObject();
    requestBean.addProperty("key", value);
    requestBean.addProperty("key", value);
    requestBean.addProperty("key", value);
    requestBean.addProperty("key", value);
    requestBean.addProperty("key", value);

    return requestBean;
}
```

3.) In case you haven't noticed you are not updating the data in the recycler view. So update data by using `addNewItem(List<CommentData> newContent)` method.

Comment: thanks my friend. do you have team viewer? please help me

Comment: yes I do have it. I'll be online after 2 and a half hours. So how should we contact?

Comment: 2.30 hour later in very later in my country . can you send me your Skype ID for speak here? please

Comment: are you here my friend?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing some data to the server in the wrong way. Are you sure that the data sent from POSTMAN are the same sent from Retrofit?

Could you post your implementation of `api.getComments(sendData)` method?